# How to convert a String to DWORD in C#

Tags: c#

When I tried to convert string to DWORD it is not converting and Exception is coming: Input String was not in Correct Format

```
string cData = File.ReadAllText(@file1Text.Text );
DWORD rData = Convert.ToUInt32(cData);
```

Comment: And what does the input string look like? Is it a valid integer?

Comment: your exception clearly says that Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: what is your input string!!! mention that in your question.

Comment: not dissimilar to your prev question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288343/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-string-to-hexadecimal-values-and-store-it-in-a-file

Comment: Coming here to ask for help but not giving enough details because you want to solve it quickly? You're not gonna get help like that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `TryParse` instead. It won't throw an exception, and if it passes then you will have the value stored in your local variable:

```
string cData = File.ReadAllText(@file1Text.Text );
DWORD rData;

if (UInt32.TryParse(cData, out rData))
{
    // If you get here, the data was valid and is now stored in rData
}
else
{
    // If you get in here, the cData was not a valid UInt32
}
```